# How does array.sort work with multidimensional arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been looking around on the internet trying to find out how to sort a multidimensional array by column and i found a way that works but I'm not sure exactly how it works. Can someone explain it to me?

```
Arrays.sort(data, (int[] num1, int[] num2) ->
    Integer number1 = num1[1];
    Integer number2 = num2[1];
    return number2.compareTo(number1);
});
```

in this care the code sorts the array [][] in descending order by the second column.

Comment: This code is for `Java 8` and uses [`lambda expressions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).  You are missing `{`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A two dimensional array is an array whose elements are arrays (int[] in your case). Therefore, in order to sort such an array, you should supply a comparator that compares `int[]` objects. This is exactly what the lambda expression in your code snippet does. It accepts two int[] objects and determines their relative order by comparing the elements at the second position (i.e. index 1) of the two arrays.

The lambda expression is a feature added in Java 8. It allows you to supply an implementation to a functional interface (which is an interface with a single method, such as `Comparator<int[]>`, whose single method is `int compare (int[] first, int[] second)`) without most of the syntax required for anonymous class instances.